# Using action in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if my question is clear, so I reformulate it :
Is it possible to call an action (quick action for example) from a lightning component (in code) ?

---

I was wondering if, in a component that I create, I can put the edit button in the image below [image]

When I click this button it open the popup below :
[image]

This button is in the lightning experience, and I'd like to put it in my code, is it possible or do I have to re-code it ?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to do something like this following this steps.

Add Lightning Inspector Chrome Extension and record event log  just before clicking the Edit Button.

There you can find which lightning event is firing the modal dialog.

Then, you could recreate it.

In my case, I was able to open select file dialog with this code :

```
({
    initializeFileDialog : function(component, event, helper) {
        var strFileDialogComponent = 'forceChatter:publisherSalesforceFileAction';

        $A.createComponent('markup://' + strFileDialogComponent , null, function(){}); 
    },    
    openFileDialog : function() {
        debugger;
        var strFileDialogComponent = 'forceChatter:publisherSalesforceFileAction';

        $A.createComponent('markup://' + strFileDialogComponent, null,
            function(objFileDialog) {
                objFileDialog.get('e.run').fire();
            }
        );
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, could you put the code of the component corresponding with this controller ?

Comment: Yes, I put the initializeFileDialog on the init of the lightning component. openFileDialog is the handler of a onclick button event. (this code is inside the component's helper)

Comment: ok, but in fact you are forced to recreate the component, for example an edit button ? Is there a way to directly put the true component into a lightning component ?